# socket.emit call everytime time when not in same scren

Tags: swift, socket.io

I am creating chat application in swift 5 in which i am adding read message functionality all are working fine. If user on chat screen and new message got at that time i fire **socket?.emit("read_status")** method but that is always call even user is not in chat screen.

I want that **socket?.emit("read_status")** should call only if user on chat screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours I found solution, I was forgot to add socket.off("read_status") method in viewWillDisAppear method